# JQuery doesnot support custom attribute in IE*?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, custom-attributes

In html I have on table like this:

`<table for="availableTimeRanges"></table>`

then I user jquery to find the table

```
var table = $("table[for='availableTimeRanges']");
```

In firefox and chrome, this works,can return the table, but in IE8, nothing return
Then i run below code in IE8, found the attribute value is empty:

```
$.each($("table"), function(i,n){
        alert($(n).attr("for")

});
```

what's the reason

Comment: `for` is not a custom attribute - it's an existing attribute (it is defined in the standard), but you're misusing it on the TABLE element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Šime Vidas said, Try Changing the name from for to something else like forparam, htmlfor, etc. (**You can not use for with a table** its for labels that are for an input)

```
$(function () {

        $('table[forparam=availableTimeRanges]').each(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('forparam'));
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You better use class names they are supported everywhere

```
<table class="for_availableTimeRanges"></table>
```

and

```
$('.for_availableTimeRanges')
```

Answer (score 0):

In think you should try wrapping your code in `$(function(){...});`

```
$(function(){
   $.each($("table"), function(i,n){
        alert($(n).attr("for")
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table data-ranges="availableTimeRanges"> </table>

var ranges = {
  set : function (options){
     options = options || [];
     //loop and set ranges
  },
  get : function(){
     $("table [data-ranges='availableTimeRanges']").each(function(){
         alert($(this).data("ranges"));
     }); 
  }
};
ranges.get // calls get method
```

Comment: A little explanation would be great :) On SO people tend to want to know "why" :)